# HTML/Expression Builder for Dynamic Labels

Tags: qgis, html, qgis-expression

Working in QGIS 3.28.2

My goal is to make a GIF that shows the routes of protests/marches that either begin/end in Malcolm X Park according to date.

I have a layer ("Protests") that has two fields: "Protest" and "Date." The Date field is just a regular date field with the date of the protest. The Protest field is the name/organizer of the protest.

I am trying to make a Title Label that has a static title ("Protests in Malcolm X Park") as well as a dynamic label that shows the date as well as the protest related to that date (like "African Liberation Day").

I am able to get the date to be dynamic, via this expression: format_date(@map_start_time,'MMMM dd, yyyy')

However, I am unable to get the "Protest" to correspond. This is what I tried, but to no avail. What am I doing wrong?:

```
aggregate(
     layer:='Protests',aggregate:='concatenate_unique',
     expression:="Protest",
     filter:=@map_start_time = "Date")
```

Comment: What settings have you made in the time tab in the layer properties?